# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio missing

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssms

I installed a named instance of SQL Server 2008 on the computer where there have been already some instances installed (they were installed without SQL Server Management Studio).

During this last full installation I included all options, including SQL Server Management Studio, but after installation I can't find SQL Server 2008 Management Studio installed.

Does it mean I should do something just to make it displayed on the list of installed SQL Server options or it didn't installed due to previously installed instances and I should first completely uninstall all instances and only then make new installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the installer and select additional options to add the client tools (I would do this against the default instance to keep things simple).

If SP1 has been installed, you might need to create a installer that slipstreams SP1 already (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638062.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/02/25/sql-server-2008-creating-a-merged-slisptream-drop.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/04/24/sql-server-2008-slipstream-frequently-asked-questions.aspx) for information on doing this).